# 'this' type inferred as 'any' in Typescript class prototype method

Tags: typescript

Say I have a class with a `_type` property and `getType` method:

```js
class Thing {
  _type: number;

  getType: () => number;
}
```

I then want to define the `getType` method outside of the class:

```js
Thing.prototype.getType = function getType() {
  return this._type;
}
```

In the `getType` definition, **this** is getting inferred as *any*, rather than the type of `Thing`. However, if `getType` is defined inside the class definition it works just fine.

What is wrong with this? Is there some syntax that needs to be used to bind **this** to the function definition?

Comment: Why would you define the method outside of the class? You could add `this: Thing` as a parameter to `getType` at the function definition.

Comment: Thanks - This is just a very basic example to show the issue, but I do this in cases where I have large classes with many methods and want to break it out into separate files.

Comment: My god It took me for ever to find this question from my googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods declared in the class will have `this` types as an instance of the class (although there is no guarantee `this` will actually be an instance of the type at runtime).

Functions defined and assigned to the prototype will o benefit from any inference for `this`, since the method signature does not actually preserve the type of `this`.

```
class Thing {
    getType() { }
}

let fn = Thing.prototype.getType // fn has type ()=> void instead of (this: Thing) =>
```

There was a discussion to better type `this`, but it's performance implications were prohibitive (10-20% perf impact on class heavy code, if I remember correctly) so it was scrapped. Although the example above makes it seem trivial, typing `this` is not easy when you take into account derived classes, as `this` would have to essentially be a type parameter, which causes  the slow down.

You can use an explicit annotation for `this` (the extra parameter will be erased during compilation):

```
Thing.prototype.getType = function getType(this: Thing) {
  return this._type;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwLAChrQH0AXATwAcBTAQgC5pkBXAWwCMKAnAbl31QqNjlqdABQBKaAF4AfPWZsuuAL65VOBClQA6MuwD2RA0K18BQqdABmDZMCKI9yaKcGURRJBBoa0E7Hmh2fgZ2Jw9ECC1iIW4cJSA)

Or, if as in your case, the method is actually declared as a field on the class, you can add the annotation for this on the field signature, and benefit from the annotation when you assign it:

```
class Thing {
  _type!: number;
  getType!: (this: Thing) => number;
}


Thing.prototype.getType = function getType() {
  return this._type;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwLAChrQH0AXATwAcBTAQgC5pkBXAWwCMKAnAbl31QqNjlqdABREkEOghSoAlNAC8APnrM2XXAF9cOnNLQA6MuwD2RM0IN8BQxdABmDZMCKITyaNcGUR87Hmh2fgZ2D3FECANiIW4cTSA)